# XSL FO Pass dynamic value from the HTML to XSLT variable

Tags: xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have trying to create pdf from html file using FOP. 
My requirement is, I want to pass variable value at run time. 
How can I pass variable value at run time?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail on how exactly you use FOP? It is not clear what "pass dynamic value from the HTML" to XSLT means exactly, do you have a HTML file that you process with XSLT? Or do you have an HTML document rendered in the browser? Do you call FOP from the command line, in some self written code? So us your current processing steps and perhaps an example of the HTML and what constitutes a "dynamic value from the HTML", then it is easier to understand where the processing can be changed to use the value in the XSLT.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen, I have one microservice which works for generating PDF. Request parameter is full url of HTML file. with help of html URL, I am  creating PDF with Java.
My simple use case is develop one microservice for creating PDF file from HTML, mixcroservice is contained one common xsl file. I trying to send variable value to XSLT file from html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear at what point you can inject "variables" nor how you expect to do them. Here's a sample that may provide some inspiration. It only uses a simple identity-translate and omits all the FO stuff for brevuty.

General principle -- put in a hidden `div` with some codes that are variables. For instance and simplicity, your input HTML now has this:

```
<html>
    <div class="variables" style="display:none">
        <div class="var_1" data-value="variable 1 value"/>
        <div class="var_2" data-value="variable 2 value"/>
        <div class="var_3" data-value="variable 3 value"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Var 1 Value: <span class="variable" data-ref="var_1"/></div>
        <div>Var 2 Value: <span class="variable" data-ref="var_2"/></div>
        <div>Var 3 Value: <span class="variable" data-ref="var_3"/></div>
    </div>
</html>
```

And you modify your XSL for a template that matches on a `span` where you want to insert the variable:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="span[@class='variable']">
        <xsl:variable name="lookup">
            <xsl:value-of select="@data-ref"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <span>
            <xsl:value-of select="//div[@class=$lookup]/@data-value"/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output of this would be:

```
<html>
<div class="variables" style="display:none">
  <div class="var_1" data-value="variable 1 value"></div>
  <div class="var_2" data-value="variable 2 value"></div>
  <div class="var_3" data-value="variable 3 value"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>Var 1 Value: <span>variable 1 value</span></div>
  <div>Var 2 Value: <span>variable 2 value</span></div>
  <div>Var 3 Value: <span>variable 3 value</span></div>
</div>
</html
```

Of course, you could expand that to include a template to strip the `div` whose class is `variables` for instance to not have it in the output or processed by your templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to the XSLT stylesheet that generates the XSL-FO that is what FOP formats.

If you are using FOP to do the XSLT transformation, the format is `-param name value` (see https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.3/running.html).  If you are using an external XSLT processor to generate the XSL-FO that you pass to FOP, then you use the format that the XSLT processor requires (which will be specified in its documentation).

The closest things to variable text in the formatting stage are `fo:marker` and `fo:table-marker`, but even the markers are set before the formatting starts, and the variability comes from not knowing where page breaks occur until the document is formatted.